# ENS name reverse is not working on Ethereum address

Tags: web3js, ethereumjs, ens, ethjs

I'm trying to both resolve and lookup using "ethjs-ens" the lookup call is working correctly. However, the `resolve` call is throwing an empty error.

The address I'm using on the `reverse` function is the one I got from calling `lookup`, I'm also logging a validation to check that both addresses are the same `console.log("is the same", address === result);`

```js
import ENS from "ethjs-ens";

//assume metamask installed
//testing on main network
const ens = new ENS({ provider: window.web3.currentProvider, network: 1 });

const address = "0x96619cd92fe0c7deaaee1c8043a7fea79cfa3e71";
const name = "example.eth";
const fn = async () => {
  try {
    const result = await ens.lookup(name);
    console.log("adddress", result);
    console.log("is the same", address === result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("lookup", e);
  }

  try {
    const resultName = await ens.reverse(address);
    console.log("name is", resultName);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("name", e);
  }
};
fn();
```

[Code live sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-brook-rsmir)

`reverse` is always failing not sure what could be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because the `address` you are using is not configured to do a reverse lookup.
 You can read about reverse resolution in the [ENS docs](https://docs.ens.domains/contract-api-reference/reverseregistrar).
Reverse resolution [EIP181](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-181).

To test your code, use:

```
const address = "0xd1220a0cf47c7b9be7a2e6ba89f429762e7b9adb";
const name = "alex.vandesande.eth";
```